# Create a Tree in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a tree control to use in AngularJS. In an attempt to do this, I'm basing my implementation on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8dPm/).

This example uses a single 'Parent' element. How could I modify this example such that I could have multiple parents? I need to have a structure like this:

```
Parent 1
  Child A
    GC I
    GC II
  Child B
Parent 2
  Child C
    GC III
  Child D
    GC IV
    GC V
    GV VI
Parent 3
   Child E
   Child F
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get multiple parent objects to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle to allow a tree to be an array!

http://jsfiddle.net/n8dPm/189/

```
<tree families="treeFamily"></tree>
```

and

```
 '<div ng-repeat="family in families">'+
            '<p>{{ family.name }}</p>'+
            '<ul>' + 
                '<li>'+
                   '<tree families="family.children"></tree>' +
                '</li>'+
            '</ul>'+
            '</div>',
```